# Can't run k-means with SPSS Modeler 16

Tags: k-means, spss, spss-modeler

I'm using IBM SPSS modeler 16.0 to analyze my data that have four fields and all of them are retrived from a database as string and converted to numbers with the node replace using `to_number()`. When I connect my node to `k-means` node to create the clusters using that data I get an error (I'm running a french version and this is a translation of the error):

```
Type not enough specified for the field 'MyField1' 
Type not enough specified for the field 'MyField2' 
Type not enough specified for the field 'MyField3' 
Type not enough specified for the field 'MyField4'
```

I tried almost everything but I can't get rid of this error. Can anyone help me to figure this out ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to instantiate the input fields used by the k-means model.
You do this by adding a 'Type' node before the modeling node and after any field operation node that would make compute or change any of the nodes that are used as input to the model.
In the 'Type' node you then make sure to click the "Read Values" button or make the proper selections for each field, which is what will instantiate the fields.
This step is not only required for the k-means model, but for most (if not all) of the modeling nodes.